# How to make build to fail depending on xml report in Jenkins Pipeline (scripted) using xunit

Tags: xml, jenkins-pipeline, xunit

I have Jenkins Pipeline where running test automation scripts and I am using Jenkins MultiBranchPipeline (not a free style) job. I want to fail or pass the jenkins build depending on the execution report which coming as xml file.

```
pipeline{

stages{

    stage('executing scripts')
    {
        'running test automation scripts '          
    }
    stage('copying artifacts')
    {
        'copying testresult.xml file into jenkins workspace output folder'
    }
}

post{
    always{

        [$class: 'XUnitBuilder',
                        thresholdMode: 1,
                        thresholds: [[$class: 'FailedThreshold', unstableThreshold: '0']],
                        tools: [[$class: 'XUnitDotNetTestType', pattern: 'Output\\testresult.xml']]]
    }
}
}
```

My testresult.xml file has 4 failed test scripts but still the Jenkins build marked green. Could you please help me on how to make my jenkins build is marked as 'failed' if any one of the test script fail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could directly use the step instead of passing the class. That's how the official documentation recommends it https://plugins.jenkins.io/xunit/#plugin-content-working-with-pipelines.

```
post {
      always{
         xunit (
                thresholds: [ failed(failureThreshold: '0') ],
                tools: [ XUnitDotNetTestType(pattern: 'Output\\testresult.xml') ]
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @ram its not working throwing exception

Comment: Any one has a solution for this ?

Comment: @reachit it is not possible to help unless you add the exception message to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkinsfile Unit tests stage for running the boost tests and stopping on failure, and the unit test reports/graphs will show in Jenkins
Precondition that xUnit plugin is installed

```
stage('Unit tests')
{
    steps
    {
       // Run tests (censored details, so line untested, but basically)
       sh 'script/run_tests.sh'
       // report unit test results, and fail build if failure
       xunit (
            thresholds: [ skipped(failureThreshold: '0'), failed(failureThreshold: '0') ],
            tools: [ BoostTest(pattern: 'unittestresults/unittests/*.xml') ]
            )
        // Make failed unit test stop the build pipeline
        script
        {
            if (currentBuild.result.equals("FAILURE")) {
               error "Test results did not pass"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The run_tests.sh script runs all unit tests with XML, and result_code=no (build details not included)

```
mkdir -p unittestresults/unittests

for test in unittests/*; do 
    echo "Running $test"
    ./$test --log_format=XML --log_sink=unittestresults/${test}_results.xml --log_level=all --report_level=no --result_code=no
done
```

All unittests build to the build root unittests folder using something similar to the following in CMakeLists.txt

```
set(PROJECT_TESTS_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}-tests)
...
...
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_TESTS_NAME} PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME "mymodule-tests"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/unittests/")
```

The build will now stop at Unit tests stage, and the unit test reports/graphs will show in Jenkins